# comparing vectors of uneven lengths in R to find unpaired portions

Tags: r

I have two vectors of uneven lengths.

```
> starts
[1]  1  4  7 11 13 15 18 20 37 41 53 61
> ends
[1]  3  6 10 17 19 35 52 60 63
```

Each corresponding part in `starts` and `ends` are supposed to form a boundary, e.g. `(1, 3)` for the first, `(4, 6)` for second, etc. However you will notice that `starts` has 10 elements, and `ends` has just 9. What happened is for some anomaly, there may be consecutive `starts`, e.g. 4th to 6th elements of `starts` (11, 13, 15) are all smaller than the 4th element of `ends` (17).

*Edit: please note also corresponding `ends` are not always 1 higher than `starts`, sample above edited to reflect so i.e. after `ends` 35, the next `starts` is 37.*

My question is, how to find all these extranuous unpaired `starts`? My aim is to lengthen `ends` to be same length as `starts`, and pair all extranuous `starts` with a corresponding `NA` in `ends`. The actual vector lengths are in thousands, with mismatches in hundreds. I can imagine a nested `for` loop to address this, but am wondering if there is a more efficient solution.

*Edit*: the expected result would be (`starts` unchanged, displayed for comparison):

```
> starts
 [1]  1  4  7 11 13 15 18 20 37 41 53 61
> ends
 [1]  3  6 10 NA NA 17 19 35 NA 52 60 63
```

or equivalent, not particular about format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> starts = c(1, 4, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27)
> ends = c(3, 5, 14, 22, 25)
> e = ends[findInterval(starts, ends)+1]
> e
[1]  3  5 14 14 22 22 25 NA
> e[duplicated(e, fromLast=T)]=NA
> e
[1]  3  5 NA 14 NA 22 25 NA
```

findInterval seems to work

Comment: This seems to do it (+1), but I find `e <- rep(NA_real_, length(starts)); e[findInterval(ends, starts)] <- ends; e` to be a little more direct than using `duplicated`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both `starts` and `ends` are sorted and that it's only in `ends` where the values are missing, you might be able to do something as straightforward as:

```
ends[c(match(starts, ends + 1)[-1], length(ends))]
#  [1]  3  6 10 NA 17 19 36 52 60 63
```

Comment: Thanks I think I begin to understand your code; very clever and succinct.

If I understand correctly, it assumes that the next `starts` is always one more than the last `ends` . I may have cases where it is not so (e.g. if `starts` is 131 and the next `ends` is 133). Would it require tweaking?

Comment: @Ricky, yes. My answer won't work in that case. I would suggest you edit your question with some sample code that would be indicative of the problem you actually have.

Comment: Thanks will do. Apologies I didn't realise that my sample didn't cover all the possibilities.